# What is this oval, small green fruit?

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, shrubs

We live in Las Vegas and have two bushes in the backyard dropping this fruit. It had a sweet taste. What is it?

[image: woman’s hand holding a small, green fruit]

[image: the small, oval green fruit cut in half]

Comment: If no one recognises the plant from the fruit, please post a photo of the plant itself

Comment: They're mini guavas.

Comment: They're kumquats...grins!!!

Comment: Brenn, come on!  Do an answer!  You know you are right...

Comment: Julia, I worry about 'tasting' something you know not!  Grins.  Not a good idea or habit...just sayin'

Comment: While they could be a mini guava - I'm not very familia with it, they could also be a variety of small/wild feijoa - Feijoa are usually quite sweet inside and very common in New Zealand, and the - As @Bamboo suggested, it would be a good idea to post a photo of the plant, and also your locality.  (Fejoas are also known as pineapple guavas)

Comment: They look like those small limes.

Comment: My vote is also pineapple guava (feijoa)

Comment: By "mini guava", I meant Feijoa. A pic of the plant would allow conclusion but I have no doubts. Take it @davidgo.

Answer (score 4):

By consensus of the thread, the answer is [Feijoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acca_sellowiana), also known as pineapple guavas!

Comment: You can eat the flower petals too, they are pretty tasty.